# Выделить матрицу признаков и целевую переменную из загруженных данных

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, scikit-learn

Верно ли я нахожу матрицу признаков и целевую переменную из [датасета](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/0fT4twJ2P-ln9w)?

Вот, что у меня получается:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linear_regression = LinearRegression()
model = linear_regression.fit(data, data.target)

weight_data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data[0:100], model.coef_)))
weight_data.columns = ['f', 'target']
print(weight_data)

         f         target
0       f1  -4.823780e-15
1       f2  -5.995204e-15
2       f3  -1.371125e-14
3       f4   2.832478e-15
4       f5   3.999419e-15
..     ...            ...
96     f97   2.167819e-14
97     f98  -8.83538@e-15
98     f99   1.346628e-14
99    f160  -1.384255e-14
100 target   9.999620e-01

[101 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сразу приведу более правильный код, а потом объясню, что и как:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
linear_regression = LinearRegression()

X = data.drop(columns='target')
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
y = data.target
model = linear_regression.fit(X, y)

weight_data = pd.DataFrame(zip(data.columns, model.coef_))
weight_data.columns = ['f', 'coeff']
weight_data = weight_data[weight_data.coeff.abs() > 0.01]
weight_data = weight_data.sort_values('coeff', ascending=False)
print(weight_data)

sns.barplot(x='coeff', y='f', data=weight_data);
plt.title('Коэффициенты/важность признаков');
```

Вывод:

```
      f       coeff
53  f54  489.356736
83  f84  370.082114
32  f33  367.383082
22  f23  285.648451
7    f8  239.417430
68  f69  179.345713
37  f38  112.168497
28  f29  107.357792
91  f92   77.969137
46  f47   12.506650
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, что тут важно:

- из матрицы признаков нужно убирать `target`, если вы его оставите, то понятно, что лучше всего `target` коррелирует сам с собой, а остальное так - случайные флуктуации, что у вас и получилось - коэффициент у `target` получился `0.9999...`, т.е. почти `1`, регрессия предсказала `target` по нему же самому
- если вы хотите посчитать реальную важность признаков, то данные нужно масштабировать, иначе коэффициенты регрессии вам покажут не совсем то, что вы, возможно ожидаете, например, если у вас есть всего два признака и один признак имеет среднее `1000`, а другой `0.001` и при этом оба одинаково важны для вычисления `target`, то у первого будет коэффициент `0.0005`, а у второго `500`, и как вы эти два числа будете сравнивать/воспринимать? а вот после масштабирования в один диапазон значений, например `[0, 1]` оба признака будут иметь коэффициент `0.5` и всё будет понятно - это два одинаково важных признака

На ваших данных у меня получилось c `LinearRegression`, что есть 10 более-менее важных признаков, а остальные имеют очень малую значимость, это просто шум.

И это я ещё не использовал регуляризацию и кросс-валидацию. А надо бы.

P.S. С `ElasticNetCV` вообще другие фичи получаются важными и как-то по-другому картина выглядит, в общем, похоже, данные не так просты, и их ещё нужно изучать. Но основные ошибки вам в общем уже указали. Дальше нужно делать кросс-валидацию, смотреть насколько точно модель предсказывает, пробовать другие модели, делать визуализацию как признаков, так и их корреляции... В общем, это работа творческая.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошо все объяснили!

Comment: Судя по данным в файле, эти данные уже прогнали через `StandardScaler` - в этом случае я бы не стал их повторно скалировать )

Comment: @MaxU Хм, возможно, возможно )

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010 Я там ещё сделал дополнение в конце, и обратите внимание на комментарий MaxU. По-хорошему нужно данные визуализировать, смотреть что там с распределениями... Работа с данными - штука в общем не простая :)

Comment: Случаем нет у вас ресурсов знакомых, где подобные темы можно достоверно изучить?

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010 Лучше сразу какой-нибудь нормальный курс пройти, например https://mlcourse.ai/ Но много и других и курсов и статей в интернете, и на ютьюбе роликов. Просто не ленитесь искать. Эта тема надолго, к ней надо серьёзно подходить, я уже лет 5 это всё изучаю и ещё изучать и изучать

Answer (score 4):

> Верно ли я нахожу матрицу признаков и
> целевую переменную из датасета

Нет, у вас логическая ошибка - в обучающей выборке присутствует целевая переменная. Вследствие чего модель может "идеально" подобрать веса коэффициент ов - `1.0` для столбца с целевой переменной и нули для всех остальных столбцов. В итоге мы получим 100% точность для обучающей выборки.

Разделите обучающую выборку на входную матрицу и целевую переменную. Кроме этого следует разделить всю выборку на две части - на обучающий и тестовый наборы. Модель при обучении не должна видеть данных из тестового набора данных. Иначе вы не сможете адекватно оценить точность модели для новых данных, т.е. для тех, которые модель не видела во время обучения:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data.drop(columns="target"), 
    data["target"],
    test_size=0.2,
    random_state=42)
```

Comment: Кстати, при разных разбиениях совсем разный скор на отложенной выборке выходит. Похоже это какие-то данные по типу случайных, специально, чтобы помучились с ними )

Comment: @CrazyElf, хмм, забавно )